# How to add html to a popover in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, hover, popover

i managed to make a popover on hover in angular using  PopoverModule from ngx-popover and this is how it works :

```
<a popover="hello" [popoverOnHover]="true"> popover</a>
```

Now i need to change that "hello" to html (add image , div ... ) 
i ve done some researches and i found this example

```html
 <ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
     [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
        I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
         </button>
```

but it didn't work ! any ideas?

Comment: Are you using 
ngx-bootstrap (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover)
or 
ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api)

Comment: I believe he is using ngx-popover: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
<a popover="hello" [popoverOnHover]="true"> popover</a>
```

needs to match the #popContent name.

Secondly, your content is a bit of a mess. You need to review the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-popover). Try something more like this. Also, learn HTML... you've got tags that aren't closed and popover attributes in your  that belong in your  instead.

I've got markup and bindings in my popover!